# How to mount curlftpfs in fstab

Tags: linux, fstab, curlftpfs

How can I permanently mount a remote FTP directory in fstab with curlftpfs, so it will be accessible for the common users on the machine?

I am using Linux Slackware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this not work?

## How can I make CurlFtpFS mount automatically at startup?

```
You can add it to /etc/fstab. Example:
  curlftpfs#ftp.host.com /mnt/host fuse rw,uid=500,user,noauto 0 0
```

---

#### Reference

http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Note that this may have security concerns. See https://superuser.com/questions/1677375/use-curlftpfs-in-a-secure-way-without-plaintext-and-world-readable-password-e/1677376